# Growing textSize in Processing

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to write a program where the text is growing so that the larger the number, the larger the font size.

I have an array from 0-9 showing on my screen but struggle to have the growth of the font size.

Does anyone have a hint for me?

My current code is:

```
int[] numbers =   {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

void setup() {
  size(800, 500);
}

void draw() {
  background(28, 130, 42);

  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    textSize(32);
    fill(51, 102, 104);
    text(""+(i), 100+(i)*50, height/2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this to be done with JavaFX or some other library ?

Comment: @Trunk Appears to be [processing](https://processing.org/) like the tag suggests, here's documentation of the [`text`](https://processing.org/reference/text_.html) method.

Comment: @Mark : Pardon me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textSize(32)` is hardcoded and not dynamic, do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    textSize(3 * i + 3);
    // Your code that draws to screen
}
```

I've changed `32` to `3 * i + 3` so your `textSize` will range from `3-30`.

Ofcourse this can be anything you want, just make sure it's some calculation based on `i`, as the loop continues `i` will increase and `fontSize` will too.

Comment: Thank you so much, that really makes sense. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @SternenkrautDelux You're welcome! Can you mark this as solved if this solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this function, where 'fontSize' is the value of the array (times n, depending on how big you want your font).

```
.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, fontSize));
```